# DiscordRP in program Java

Tags: java, discord

I wanted to add DiscordRP in my program, which means that when the program is running it is displayed in the Discord application, can it be done?

Comment: What is a DiscordRP? Do you mean rich presence? Bots can't use rich presence.

Comment: Do you mean https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#update-status method? What have you tried so far? Please let us show your code. Intro: https://www.toptal.com/chatbot/how-to-make-a-discord-bot

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, you need to look up creating Discord bots in java. There are Discord RP bots that already exist.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxOxcgbikJo

This tutorial is helpful, I reccomend other online sources.